# Kernel panic - Not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000009

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I have a laptop that came preinstalled with Ubuntu 14.04 and has had minimal issues until now.  Upon booting I am presented with the following kernel panic:

[image: Kernel panic]

After forcefully shutting down the machine I can get back into the bootloader and either try again (which reproduces the same kernel panic) or go into Advanced options for Ubuntu and select a different kernel version:

[image: kernel Selection in GRUB]

Selecting any of the non-safe mode kernels in the list except the newest one, 3.13.0-58, will allow me to boot the machine and use it (typing this question from the laptop in question).  I checked my log for apt (/var/log/apt/history.log) and found that during an upgrade I did yesterday the system installed kernel 3.13.0-58 and the problem showed up after this event.

My main concern here is that the kernel panic appears to be from when the system tries to set the target cpu frequency and either it fails to set it or some integrity check fails but I don't know nearly enough to actually figure it out.  I do not think it is a hardware problem because using any of the older kernels boots (and appears stable, has been running for over 2 hours on 3.13.0-38).  Could it be a hardware issue which I should get an RMA for or is it a conflict between my existing system and the new kernel?  If it is indeed a software issue how do I resolve it?  Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I was experiencing seemed to be a temporary one.  A few days since posting a new kernel version has been made available for my system (3.13.0-58.97).  After updating to this latest version the kernel panic has stopped and the system behaves as expected.  Somewhat silly but for anyone else with this issue you can simply revert to an older kernel until a newer patch is made available.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from whichever kernel that works. Open terminal and enter **sudo apt-get autoremove**. This should remove any old kernel image files. I had the same problm with the same laptop (:P) and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I've also this problem. Tested on two Acer TM (TravelMate) B115. One manufactured on 2014/07/15 (TMB115-M-C1MW) and the other on 2015/06/25 (TMB115-M-C2ZM).
The problem disappears if the computers are booted without the power charger. Very curious!

For "generic" kernels:

3.13.0-46 works fine.
3.13.0-62 and 3.13.0-63 have the problem.
3.19.0-26 works fine but Synaptic ClickPad (TouchPad) is not well supported. It's seen only like a mouse. xinput command shows SYN1B7D:01 06CB:2991 unknown

To migrate to 3.19 kernel you need to follow https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:i386
```

Fortunately I found that the BIOS has an option to configure the TouchpPad mode (Basic or Advanced). It says:

Please make sure I2C driver is installed before Advanced feature enabled. Otherwise, touchpad will be no function.

I changed this option from Advanced to Basic and now the TouchPad for the latest TMB115 works fine. xinput command recognizes it. So, I understand the TouchPad is working in usb mode, not in i2c mode. http://www.synaptics.com/en/intertouch.php

Using 3.19 kernel guvcview from 14.04 repository (1.7) doesn't work. guvcview 2.0 is needed. It can be installed from https://launchpad.net/~pj-assis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa