# Why does Lubuntu 14.04 Kernel Panic on boot when Notebook is connected to AC Power, but not when on battery

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, lubuntu, cpufreq

since Ubuntu kernel 3.13.0-59 (or possibly even -58) Lubuntu kernel panics on Acer Travelmate B115-M when the device is connected to AC, but not when it's starts with battery only.

Older kernels still work fine.

it seems to panic while setting cpu governor policy - I see there might be a connection, but I have no BIOS-options to change anything about the behaviour. I already asked Acer for BIOS Updates - didn't get any answer yet.

Do you have any hints?
did you ever experience sth. similar? (And what did you do about it?)
Is there something i could set or check?

Since there are 19 other identical devices out there which I'm responsible for and 3 are already affected, it's a bit worrying ...

Comment: What is Lubuntu version?

Comment: as it said 14.04 (14.04.1 LTS Trusty Tahr to be precise)

Comment: It seems strange that only 3 out of 19 machines are affected. Any idea why the other 16 are not?

Comment: they didn't have the update yet. since they will automatically update whenever they are connected for a longer period, they will be affected soon.

Comment: Same problem. You can find my answer at http://askubuntu.com/a/670283/358831

Comment: Same problem. Please see my answer at http://askubuntu.com/a/670283/358831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kernel 3.13.0-59 seems to be buggy. There a number of reports, that installation of this kernel causes various problems.

Probably some backport was not very good.

I suggest switching to kernel 3.19 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

Comment: I tried it on my example device and it worked here. I'm going to deploy it on the other affected machines and report back. Thanks a lot!

Comment: installed it on another 8 Machines and it works. Looks like 3.13.59 really is buggy and this bug isn't present in 3.19.0-25 anymore. thanks!

Comment: Now deployed on all 20 machines and no more problems so far.