# Ubuntu 16.04 desktop end Kernel panic - not syncing : Attempted to kill init! exit code=0x00000009

Tags: system-installation, kernel

My laptop is Asus N551VW. I use Windows and I just wanted to try Ubuntu but there is a problem when I wanna install Ubuntu.

Refer this image:

[image]

I don't know any thing about Linux.

Comment: Check this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/651974/kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-exitcode-0x00000009 Try their solutions.

Comment: I have checked that before but it doesn't help . i do not even know what is a kernel

Comment: A kernel is the main program that boots the computer (simply). See [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) and [2](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(computer_science)).

Comment: Your system is in a really bad state.

Comment: What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread:

[Kernel Panic - Not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000009](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651974/kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-exitcode-0x00000009)

Read throught it, hope it helps.