# End Kernel Panic - Not Syncing attempted to kill init! (18.04)

Tags: boot, kernel, init

On starting Ubuntu, it just showed purple screen for 5 min. so I switched off the laptop. When I started, it showed "Unexpected inconsistency: Run fsck manually" so I did it using `fsck /dev/sda6/ -y` command. After rebooting, I'm getting a new error as seen in the screenshot below.

[image: End kernel panic - Not syncing attempted to kill init!]

Please help me regarding this. I have valuable data stored in Ubuntu!

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I've also ran memtest86 and in the advanced option tried each old kernel:
5.4.0-56(general), 5.4.0-56(recovery mode), 5.4.0-54(general), 5.4.0-54(recovery mode).
But the problem still persists.

**UPDATE2**
I've have two RAMs 4GB each. So, I've also tried using only one RAM at a time in each slot, to check whether the error is coming due to a faulty RAM and identify it, but still nothing!

Comment: The good news is, it doesn't look like a faulty hard drive.  If you can, try selecting the Memtest from the grub menu and run through a full test.  Looks like it might be faulty RAM in the system.  You can also create a Live USB/CD/DVD on another system and boot to it then you could see about backing up your data.

Comment: Have you installed new updates recently? Have you tried pressing shift during boot and using 'advanced' to boot with previously working kernels? You should run a live USB and backup your data ASAP.

Comment: @Katu No, I haven't.

Comment: Can you please try to boot and select 'advanced' option in GRUB? You will see a list of previous kernels and options to boot 'normal' or 'safe mode'. Try all of them and if one works, backup and run an upgrade again. If none work, please update your question with that information.

Comment: @Katu Should I do memtest first as suggested by Terrence?

Comment: @Chris yes, that is a good suggestion.

Comment: @Katu I've updated the info. Done memtest86 and each old kernel but nothing.

Comment: @Terrance memtest86 done but no progress.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kernel panic - Not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000009](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651974/kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-exitcode-0x00000009)

Comment: @karel I don't think so! Because I've checked every old kernel in the "Advanced options" but still the error remains.

Comment: It didn't work, so I retracted the close vote.

Comment: One other thing I guess to check is what is the hard drive mode set for in the BIOS?  If it is anything else other than AHCI, try setting it to AHCI.  Also, try creating a Live USB/DVD to eliminate any hardware problems.  If it kernel panics still with a Live boot, then you might be looking deeper like possible CPU, which normally will show that, or a bad motherboard.

Comment: @Terrance I've checked AHCI is enabled. I haven't tried the Live USB to boot to Ubuntu. But if it still doesn't boot then why it should be a motherboard problem? I have dual boot and windows is working fine! Also, if it boots fine then what should I do? Will my data be there and would I be able to copy it to other USB?

Comment: Yeah, your data should still be there.  Copying it to a USB drive should be fine.  Live USB should allow you to mount your drive in the Try Ubuntu and then you should be able to copy your data.

Comment: @Terrance I can boot to Ubuntu using USB. I've copied some data but some I'm not able to due to permission denied error. Any solution?  Also, is there any log file I should see to know exactly why Ubuntu is not booting normally?

Comment: @Katu Sorry to bother you but have you seen the updates I've made and read the comments. Please suggest if there's something that needs to be tried.

Comment: @Chrisbgd coments are not meant for extended discussion. If you can boot from USB, you can backup everything and reinstall. The permission denied error can be solved running the command with sudo. Something like `sudo rsync -va --progress orig_folder dest_folder` should backup your data. I have no other suggestions, good luck!