# ERROR CODE 0x00000009

Tags: server

Every time I attempt to install Ubuntu Server, I consistently encounter the error code 0x00000009. Despite trying various available versions of Ubuntu Server, I have not been successful in resolving this issue. I am uncertain about the root cause of this error and am seeking guidance on potential troubleshooting steps or alternative approaches to successfully install Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Exactly when in the process does this error come up?

Comment: Some hardware details might help you get useful answers. What kernel and version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: same: https://askubuntu.com/a/670283/15811  solution: keep the charger inserted during installation. https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/can-someone-help-with-kernel-panic-code-0x00000009.3564526/  claims too old hardware so older LTS used

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kernel panic - Not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000009](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651974/kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-exitcode-0x00000009)